# google spreadsheet api for arabic

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, google-api-java-client, google-sheets-api, google-api-client

I am trying to read a spreadsheet using google spreadsheet api.
Everything went well, but when I put russian or arabic texts in the spreadsheet
my program prints ?????? ?? ????? values for those cell values.
below is the code to read spreadsheet from my google account.

```
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MyApp");
        service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

URL feedUri = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?title-exact=true&title=internationalization_contents");

        // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(feedUri, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(0);

        // get the first work sheet
        WorksheetEntry workSheet = spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0);
        URL cellFeedUrl = workSheet.getCellFeedUrl();
        CellFeed cellFeed = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);

        List<CellEntry> entries = cellFeed.getEntries();
        for (int n = 0; n < entries.size(); n++) {
            Cell cell = entries.get(n).getCell();
            System.out.println(cell.getValue());
        }
```

this prints something like

title
welcome
???? ?? ????

anybody knows how to get characters properly to my java application.